# Как плавно увеличить высоту блока?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Использую функцию `.animate()`:

```
$('.more_text').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    var text = $(this).siblings('.why-i-cont-txt-body');
    text.animate({
        // width: 400,
        height:'100%',
        opacity: 1 
    }, 2000);
});
```

При этом в стилях блока:

```
.txt-body-more {
    max-height: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Нужно изменить `max-height` на `100%`, при этом у меня блок резко открывается, а плавности нет.

Comment: Может, у вас браузер старый, или компьютер слабый, или параллельно компьютер ещё чем-то нагружен? У меня в [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nex7amut/) анимации более-менее плавно идёт.

Comment: нет просто не срабатывает версия браузера хром самая последняя

Comment: А в представленном fiddle анимация у вас тоже резко проходит?

Comment: @Regent, он пытается менять max-height - в этом случае анимация вообще не срабатывает (по крайней мере, прописанная в css).

Comment: @Regent, хотя нет, я не прав. Срабатывает. http://jsfiddle.net/1mr99f6g/

Comment: @Regent добавьте  это в ответ я отмечу его как правильный, спасибо

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте вот так:

```
text.animate({
        // width: 400,
        height:'100%',
        opacity: 1,
        -webkit-transition: 1s ease-out;
        -moz-transition: 1s ease-out;
        -o-transition: 1s ease-out;
        transition: 1s ease-out; 
    }, 2000);
```